# How to solve sweating slab syndrome?

Tags: tile

I live in a 4 floor condominium in Makati, Philippines.
Recently, I noticed that my floor always feels damp. 
My unit is at the 4th floor.
When I tried seaching it in the internet, I think it is a sweating slab syndrome issue. 
However, articles in the internet do not have a clear description on how to solve this. 
Is this something that can only be prevented but cannot be fixed once it is already there?

Comment: Have you checked you don't have a leak anywhere? In my old apartment building one of the neighbours had a faulty water connection in the concrete floor which was leaking ever so slightly. Fast forward 6 months to where the water had penetrated the concrete in a ~9 meter radius from the point of the leak and the linoleum flooring in the hallway started to lift. It was such a small leak that it was only noticed after it had done significant damage.

Comment: maybe your downstairs neighbors crank their AC, keeping your floor colder than the dewpoint in your unit. You can also cool your place more, or use a dehumidifier to raise the dewpoint.

Comment: @yetanothercoder I have not yet inquired from our building administrator. So I still don't know the layout of the piping in our building. However, when I tried observing my tiles, the tile grout is dry but the tile surface is moist. So, I'm thinking I might not be due to a leak.

Comment: @dandavis Yes, I'm thinking of doing both. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moisture, (and more precisely “condensation”) is the cause of sweating slab syndrome.

There are several causes: 1) lack of ventilation, 2) rapid change in Dew Point, 3) negative air pressure in living unit, 4) concrete slab sealed,

1) Air movement will “dry” moisture.

2) This is what I call, “The coke bottle effect.” If you take a coke bottle out of the refrigerator, it will immediately have condensation form on it. In your case, if your room is at 70 degrees with 50% relative humidity and a warm front moves in at 80 degrees and 80% relative humidity, then the Dew Point will change and NON-ABSORBENT surfaces will swear.

3) We design most buildings to have “positive” air pressure. If you have a negative air pressure, you’ll allow damp air into your environment which you’ll need to treat.

4) If your slab has been sealed, there’s no place for moisture to go, except lay on top of the slab.

You’ll need to experiment with fixing these items to correct sweating slab syndrome.

Comment: I heard some swearing in my basement  when a warm front came in.